# delete link is not appearing after file is successfully uploaded

Tags: fine-uploader

This is my second project using fineuploader, earlier I used 3.9.0, so I'm not a total newbie.  The first project showed a 'delete' link on the 'success' element.  For this project I installed fineuploader 4.0.3

This project is not showing the 'delete' link after the file is uploaded.  My initialization code is:

```
$('#bootstrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    debug: true,
    request: {
        endpoint: 'assets/php/fineuploader-endpoint.php'
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true, // defaults to false
        endpoint: 'fineuploader-delete.php?uuid='
    },
    template: 'qq-template-bootstrap',
    classes: {
        success: 'alert alert-success',
        fail: 'alert alert-error'
    }
}).on('complete',function(event,id,name,responseJson) {
var fullName = responseJson.uploadFolder+'/'+responseJson.uploadName;
    $(this).fineUploader('setName',id,fullName);
    $(this).fineUploader('setDeleteFileParams', fullName, id);      
});
```

note that I had to write a delete handler fineuploader-delete.php, modify the fineupload-endpoint.php and write the 'complete' callback function to support deleting.

These are tested and work when I execute this from the chrome debugger:

```
$('#bootstrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader('deleteFile',0);
```

So my only problem is that the qq-upload-list li does not show a link to call the delete script

Thanks!

Comment: What does your template look like?

Comment: I used your default template.  Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the information requested, I'll have to assume that you simply neglected to provide the delete file element in your template.  To ensure that the delete file button appears when using Fine Uploader UI, you must include any element somewhere in your template that includes the class "qq-upload-delete-selector".  For example:

```html
<button class="qq-upload-delete-selector">Delete</button>
```

or:

```html
<button class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
```

or:

```html
<a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
```

The last two will include style applied by Fine Uploader's CSS file, assuming you have included it in your document.

More information in the [styling portion of the documentation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/styling.html).